# Redirect to normal user/Activated user page after login

Tags: php, html

Please help i have a login page all setup and connected to my remote database

```
     id_number    username   password        UserLevel
        1         user         user            1
        2         Activeuser   ActiveUser      2
```

, i want to be able to use UserLevel to redirect users to their respective pages i.e normal user with userlevel '1' to dashboard.php while Activated user with userlevel '2' to Dashboardactivated.php.

Have already added server behavour in dreamweaver but it only seems to login normal user with userlevel '1' while Activated user with userlevel '2' gets redirected to same page.
Please how do i do it bear with me i am new to the world of coding so am working with dreamweaver as i cant write the codes myself.

Here's my code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/CashSpray.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_Login = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
  $colname_Login = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_CashSpray, $CashSpray);
$query_Login = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Login, "text"));
$Login = mysql_query($query_Login, $CashSpray) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Login = mysql_fetch_assoc($Login);
$totalRows_Login = mysql_num_rows($Login);
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['UserName'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['UserName'];
  $password=$_POST['Password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "UserLevel";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "dashboard.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "log-in.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = true;
  mysql_select_db($database_CashSpray, $CashSpray);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT Username, Password, UserLevel FROM users WHERE Username=%s AND Password=%s",
  GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $CashSpray) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {

    $loginStrGroup  = mysql_result($LoginRS,0,'UserLevel');

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US"><head><!-- Created by Artisteer v4.3.0.60745 -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Log In!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = device-width">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">
    <!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.ie7.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.responsive.css" media="all">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="script.responsive.js"></script>
    <script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationPassword.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
    .art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-0 { padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;  }
.ie7 .art-post .art-layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }
.ie6 .art-post .art-layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }

    </style>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationPassword.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="art-main">
<header class="art-header">

    <div class="art-shapes">
        <div class="art-object111552341"></div>
<div class="art-object1196905085"></div>

            </div>








</header>
<nav class="art-nav">
    <div class="art-nav-inner">
    <ul class="art-hmenu"><li><a href="home.php" class="">Home</a></li><li><a href="how-it-works.php" class="">How It Works</a></li><li><a href="sign-up.php" class="">Sign Up</a></li><li><a href="log-in.php" class="active">Log In</a></li><li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact Us</a></li></ul> 
        </div>
    </nav>
<div class="art-sheet clearfix">
<div class="art-pageslider">

     <div class="art-shapes">
            </div>
<div class="art-slider art-slidecontainerpageslider" data-width="880" data-height="250">
    <div class="art-slider-inner">
<div class="art-slide-item art-slidepageslider0">


</div>
<div class="art-slide-item art-slidepageslider1">


</div>
<div class="art-slide-item art-slidepageslider2">


</div>
<div class="art-slide-item art-slidepageslider3">


</div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="art-slidenavigator art-slidenavigatorpageslider" data-left="1" data-top="0">
<a href="#" class="art-slidenavigatoritem"></a><a href="#" class="art-slidenavigatoritem"></a><a href="#" class="art-slidenavigatoritem"></a><a href="#" class="art-slidenavigatoritem"></a>
</div>


</div>
<div class="art-layout-wrapper">
                <div class="art-content-layout">
                    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
                        <div class="art-layout-cell art-content"><article class="art-post art-article">


                <div class="art-postcontent art-postcontent-0 clearfix"><div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-0" style="width: 100%" >
        <h2><img width="76" height="81" alt="" class="art-lightbox" src="images/user-login-icon-29.png"><span style="font-weight: bold;"><span style="font-family: Georgia; color: #065179;">Log In!</span></span></h2><h2><span style="font-weight: bold;"><span style="font-family: Georgia; font-size: 20px;">Please Enter Your Correct Details!..</span></span></h2><h2><span style="font-weight: bold;"><br></span></h2>
        <form action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="LoginForm" id="LoginForm">
          <table width="500" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span id="sprytextfield1">
                <label for="UserName"></label>
UserName <br>
                <input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName">
                <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span id="sprypassword1">
                <label for="Password"></label>
Password <br>
                <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password">
                <span class="passwordRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><p>&nbsp;
                </p>
                <p>
                  <input name="LoginButton" type="submit" class="art-button" id="LoginButton" value="Login">
                </p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Dont Have An Account Yet? <a href="sign-up.php"><u>Sign Up.</u></a></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
        <h2><span style="font-weight: bold;"><br></span></h2><h2><span style="font-weight: bold;"><br></span></h2><h2><span style="font-weight: bold;"><br></span></h2><h2><span style="font-weight: bold;"><br></span></h2><h2><span style="font-weight: bold;"><br></span></h2><h2><span style="font-weight: bold;"><br></span></h2><h2><span style="font-weight: bold;"><br></span></h2><h2><span style="font-weight: bold;"><br></span></h2><h2><span style="font-weight: bold;"><br></span></h2><h2><span style="font-weight: bold;"><br></span></h2><h2><span style="font-weight: bold;"><br></span><br></h2>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>



</article></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<footer class="art-footer">
  <div class="art-footer-inner">
<div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-0" style="width: 100%">
        <p><span style="font-size: 16px; color: #FFFFFF;">Copyright © 2017, CASHSPRAY. All Rights Reserved.</span></p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <p class="art-page-footer">
        <span id="art-footnote-links">Designed by <a href="cashspray.com" target="_blank">CashSpray</a>.</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</footer>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield1");
var sprypassword1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationPassword("sprypassword1");
</script>
</body></html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Login);
?>
```

Comment: your code is a mess. please use mysqli prepared statements / pdo prepared statements,  so you can have a clean code

Comment: why would someone upvote such question

Comment: no idea. he has 0 knowledge and i put in some random code as answer that should just work fine. but he cant even get an simple if statement to work.

Comment: and why the jquerry tag. this is an php/sql related problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can write something with an IF statement. 
like

```
 IF( userlevel == 1 )
 {
   header:location "dashboard.php"
 }
 ELSE
 {
   header:location "dashboardactivated.php"
 }
```

this is not the complete syntax so u will have to correct this if you are going to use this

and if there are more than 2 user levels. u can add an ELSEIF to get more options.

ADDITION

```
if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true) {
     $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
   }
     IF( userlevel == 1 )
     {
       header:location "dashboard.php"
     }
     ELSE
     {
       header:location "dashboardactivated.php"
     }
 }
 else {
   header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
 }
}
```

WORKING ADDITION

```
         $sql2="SELECT * FROM admins WHERE Username='$Username' and Password='$Password'";
         $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
         $count2=mysql_num_rows($result2);


         $sql1="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Username='$Username' and Password='$Password'";
         $result=mysql_query($sql1);
         $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

         if($count==1){
              $_SESSION['user'] = $Username;
              header("Location:index.php");
         }
         else if($count2==1){
              $_SESSION['admin'] = $Username;
              header("Location:indexAdmin.php");
         }
         else{
         echo " Nee, Cy@";
         }
         }
         }
```

this above is something that i had in one of my sites. this works. if an admin logs in. it takes him to the admin page. and if an user logs in it takes him to the normal page. so try something that looks like this,

Comment: Please where would i add this 'if' statement?.

Comment: added some code to my answer thats where it should be. but you can see the correct syntax in the else statement header("location: ". "flocation.php")

Comment: Still cant get this to work for me, am getting a syntax errors. please how do i make it work?

Comment: well i added something again. that thing works in one of my hobby projects. so you should be able to imitate this code with your variables.

Comment: and please. what are you doing if you cant even get an if statement to work. there is enough documentation on this kind of problem

Comment: Thanks Alot for your help, i was able to figure it out, with Dreamweaver i restricted access to admin page den redirected to the normal user page, however when the user level changes he can access the activated page.

Comment: Cannu click the hook then? If this post has been answered